# Skype sdk error "Configuration service is unreachable"

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

Iam using skype js sdk

first : iam searching for any cdn that hold `skypebootstap.js` and i didn't find a one

second : when i try to sign in using code below

```
Skype.initialize({ apiKey: config.apiKey }, function (api) {
        config.application = new api.application();
        signIn();
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);  
    });
```

i got error with code 1 and message `Configuration service is unreachable`
what can cause this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check every thing related here [SkypeSDk](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples)

and the only provider for this file is swx.cdn.skype.com has turn them off.

Check your internet connection if it allow to connect Skype services.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about Skype developer but I think I can answer your question. I think the reason that you are having trouble is because you typed "Skypebootstap" when I think you meant "Skypeboot*strap*". I would like to remind you I don't know very much about Skype developer. If this is not the whole code which, I personally, don't think it is take 30 seconds took look through and find a "function" or whatever you call them on Skype that is misnamed "Skypebootstap" and change it to "Skypeboot*strap*" without the "" and add the .js.
Have a happy day :)
PS. I hope it worked

Comment: Thanks for replying, the code is working on another machines so it must be a local machine configuration,